# Adicionar o atributo "required" após alteração em "select"

Tags: javascript

No meu sistema, há três tipo de usuários:

- Administrador Geral;
- Administrador; e
- Cliente.

O *Cliente* não tem acesso ao sistema, logo, ele não precisa de senha e não seria obrigatório seu e-mail (já que ele não faria login).

Gostaria de que quando o *Administrador Geral* fosse escolher entre *Cliente* ou *Administrador*, ao selecionar Administrador, aparecesse um `input` para colocar sua senha, e adicionasse o `required` para o *input* do e-mail; e ao selecionar Cliente, fosse desfeito.

Consegui fazer a parte de mostrar e esconder o *input*, porém gostaria de saber como adicionar o *required* ao e-mail.

```js
$("#tipo").change(function() {
  $('#senha').hide();
  if (this.value == "Administrador")
    $('#senha').show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="tipo" id="tipo">
  <option value="Cliente">Cliente</option>
  <option value="Administrador">Administrador</option>
</select>
<input type="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail">
<input required="" type="password" name="senha" id="senha" style="display:none;" placeholder="Senha">
```

Comment: `$('[name="email"]').prop('required', true);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode adicioar o atributo usando `attr` e remover com `removeAttr`, já que está usando jQuery.

Veja o exemplo abaixo. Adicionei um id ao email e uma tag form para esse exemplo:

```js
$("#tipo").change(function() {
  if (this.value == "Administrador") {
    $('#senha').show();
    $('#email').attr('required','required');
  } else {
    $('#senha').hide();
    $('#email').removeAttr('required');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <select name="tipo" id="tipo">
    <option value="Cliente">Cliente</option>
    <option value="Administrador">Administrador</option>
  </select>
  <br />
  <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="E-mail" >
  <br />
  <input required="" type="password" name="senha" id="senha" style="display: none;" placeholder="Senha">
  <br />
  <input type="submit" value="Clique aqui para simular o submit" />
</form>
```

Documentação: https://api.jquery.com/attr/